# Android: Split Actionbar is not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, splitactionbar

So I'm trying to get my Actionbar to split, but it just won't happen here's my code I'm currently using:

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ChooseLocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/topMenuButton"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.vincent.projectw.ChooseLocationActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/mLocations"
    android:title="Locaties"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_marker"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/mSearch"
    android:title="Zoeken"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/mMap"
    android:title="Kaart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_world"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/mAddArticle"
    android:title="Toevoegen"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

The theme I'm using is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", and I am importing "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity", I am using APK 11 but it should work since I'm using the correct metadata? So why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

To split your `ActionBar` for API level 14 and higher, you must specify the attribute `uiOptions` on your `activity` tag (or `application`) and not `android:uiOptions`.

This is the example from the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar):

```
<manifest ...>
    <activity uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ... >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity>
</manifest>
```